# .Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am trying to send a broadcast to pusher 6.18.8 in laravel 6 but i am getting the following error

```
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1D4U.png)

my pusher config

```
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            // 'encrypted' => false,
            // 'useTLS' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 60001,
            'scheme' => 'http'
        ],
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:*********************
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://
DB_HOST=localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

I have cleared my config and cache so many times but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have also correctly set the environment variables for:

```
PUSHER_APP_KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET
PUSHER_APP_ID
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER
```

I believe the issue is related to setting the following:

```
 'host' => '127.0.0.1',
 'port' => 60001,
 'scheme' => 'http'
```

This will override the default host and port being used by the Pusher driver. The Pusher package will resolve this itself using the PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER.

If you remove the host/port/scheme options and try again this should work.

You can also check this against the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites